# How can I Iteratively create objects using the names within a Dict in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, for-loop, dynamic-programming

**Example:**

I have a dict named *basket*:

```
basket = { 'apples': 4,
          'bananas': 3, 
          'oranges': 1, 
         'grenades': 1 }
```

I want to use a for loop in this manner:

```
for i in basket:
      i = object()
```

Just to use the name each string in the dict as the object name.

**Effectively**, I'd like to use it within a class:

```
for i in basket:
      self.i = object()
```

EDIT: To avoid this being an XY Question -- I want to take a dict and iterate it to make a widget for each key in an app using PyQt5.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you really trying to accomplish? This is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: What is wrong with simply using the dictionary as it is? A class is a glorified dictionary (I will be shot for saying this) anyway.

Comment: This is indeed almost certainly an XY problem, but you can do it (if you must) using [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

Comment: Oh new concept the XY problem - gotcha -- well I have a dict and I want to generate a bunch of widgets according to how many keys I have in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *can* do the following but you **shouldn't** as it is bad practice:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        basket = {'apples': 4,
                  'bananas': 3, 
                  'oranges': 1, 
                  'grenades': 1}

        for key, value in basket.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

You can then do the following:

```
>>> obj = MyClass()
>>> obj.apples
>>> 4
```

Comment: Or do the right thing, and use a dictionary: `self.items[key] = value` and access as `obj.items['apples']`

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes, that's the correct way as I commented above (or simply `self.items = basket.copy()`)